# Regex only finds results once

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find any text between a '>' character and a new line, so I came up with this regex:

```
result = re.search(">(.*)\n", text).group(1)
```

It works perfectly with only one result, such as:

```
>test1
(something else here)
```

Where the result, as intended, is

```
test1
```

But whenever there's more than one result, it only shows the first one, like in:

```
>test1
(something else here)
>test2
(something else here)
```

Which should give something like

```
test1\ntest2
```

But instead just shows

```
test1
```

What am I missing? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Instead of `(something else here)`, please post some actual sample inputs and their outputs.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, I'm just trying to simplify it, since (something else here) isn't used for the shown code, only the fact that it includes a new line (\n). Anyway it should be a code like AAECAR8AD40BqAK1A+sH2wntCYEK/gzquwKOwwLXzQLd0gL70wLh4wKL5QIA

Comment: What would be the result of `t1\nt2\nt3`?

Comment: It's hard to write it in this kind of comment as I'm not able to add new lines, but it should be the result of something like this: >t1\n(something)\n>t2\n(something)\n>t3\n(something)\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.search` only returns the first match, as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance.

To find all the matches, use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found.

Here's an example from the shell:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(">(.*)\n", ">test1\nxxx>test2\nxxx")
['test1', 'test2']
```

Edit: I just read your question again and realised that you want "test1\ntest2" as output. Well, just join the list with `\n`:

```
>>>  "\n".join(re.findall(">(.*)\n", ">test1\nxxx>test2\nxxx"))
'test1\ntest2'
```

Comment: Thank you! It throws a AttributeError though

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @b0ss192301 No you don't need to group it. Did you even read the whole answer? The list contains group 1. Since you want all the matches, they are put into a list. Do you want them in another data structure? All joined together as a single string?

Comment: Okay I missed that, thank you very much. It's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
y = re.findall(r'((?:(?:.+?)(?:(?=[\n\r][^\n\r])\n|))+)', text)
```

Which returns `['t1\nt2\nt3']` for `'t1\nt2\nt3\n'`. If you simply want the string, you can get it by:

```
s = y[0]
```

Although it seems **much** larger than your initial code, it will give you your desired string.

## Explanation -

`((?:(?:.+?)(?:(?=[\n\r][^\n\r])\n|))+)` is the regex as well as the match.

`(?:(?:.+?)(?:(?=[\n\r][^\n\r])\n|))` is the non-capturing group that matches any text followed by a newline, and is repeatedly found one-or-more times by the `+` after it.

`(?:.+?)` matches the actual words which are then followed by a newline.
`(?:(?=[\n\r][^\n\r])\n|)` is a non-capturing conditional group which tells the regex that if the matched text is followed by a newline, then it should match it, **provided that the newline is not followed by another newline or carriage return**
`(?=[\n\r][^\n\r])` is a positive look-ahead which ascertains that the text found is followed by a newline or carriage return, and then some non-newline characters, which combined with the `\n|` after it, tells the regex to match a newline.

Granted, after typing this big mess out, the regex is pretty long and complicated, so you would be better off implementing the answers you understand, rather than this answer, which you may not. However, this seems to be the only one-line answer to get the **exact output** you desire.